# How can I lock the screen in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xfce

Xubuntu 14.04 uses [Light Locker](http://xubuntu.org/news/14-04-release/) and it is advised that one uninstalls `xscreensaver`.

Is it possible to lock the screen or do I have to install some other program for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the panel, click on panel --> Add New Items, and click on Action Buttons, and then click on add.

After you click add you will notice that your user name appears in the upper right hand corner of the screen

[image]

Click on your name on the upper right corner of the screen

[image]

and then click on lock screen

[image]

Comment: or you could use `ctrl`+`alt`+`L` to lock directly from the keyboard

Comment: @misterjinx I just tried that in Xubuntu, and it doesn't work.  Can you test it, and let me k now if it works in Xubuntu?  Thanks

Comment: oh, sorry, you're right, the default shortcut for this is `ctrl`+`alt`+`delete`, but I changed it a long time ago (and that's why I forgot) to `ctrl`+`alt`+`L` from `settings` -> `keyboard` -> `application shortcuts` -> `xflock4` -> double click on the default shortcut and record the desired one

Comment: interestingly  enough, the shorctut doesnt work for me either, although it says `ctrl+alt+del`   in the settings. no matter what shortcut I assign, no locking happens.

Comment: nvmd, answer is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101806/why-doesnt-my-screen-lock-in-xfce